# No events trigger and buttons are not pressable

Tags: c#, winforms

When creating a winforms application I added a pannel as a header so I could make the application borderless, I was going to add some buttons when I realised no events were getting registered by the program. Have I flicked a wrong switch somewhere?

I have already tried clicking the main form and changing the AutoValidation as well as checking that the form, as well as the panel, were both enabled.

```cs
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TopBar_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Expect result is that it should just close the application when I hover over the topbar or when I click the ExitButton.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this by going through the properties of the Forms/Buttons and resetting them as it turns out I had one item disabled.

Comment: This is a self-answer by the author of the question.

Comment: @karel That's fine. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer